# GDPR - jQuery Iframe Consent

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to build a opt-in dialog for iframes, which are embed in a website. The goal is, that the Iframe is not being loaded before the user has given his consent. Reason: according to GDPR the IP-adress must not be transferred without the users permission.

This is my code so far:

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="map">
  <div id="opt-in">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h3>GDPR Notice</h3>
      <p>.....................................</p>
      <button class="confirm">Accept</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var CookieGet = Cookies.get("gmapsConsent");
    if (CookieGet != null) {
      jQuery("#opt-in").hide();
      jQuery("#opt-in").after('<iframe class="google-maps" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/..."></iframe>');
    }
    
    else {
      jQuery("#opt-in .confirm").click(function() {
        Cookies.set("gmapsConsent", "1", { expires: 100 });
        jQuery("#opt-in").hide();
        jQuery("#opt-in").after('<iframe class="google-maps" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/..."></iframe>');
      });
    }
  });
</script>

</div>
```

What I can see is, that the cookie only gets set by clicking the button, so this seems to work. But I want to know for sure, whether the Iframe is being loaded before the click (= IP-adress is transferred) or only after the click/consent.

I am unsure, because the Iframe src is simply coded within the html wrapper, independently of the consent.

I hope everything is understandable. English is not my first language.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Iframe (same as any tag that get URL) only send data when it's added to DOM. Open dev tools in Chrome and switch to Network tab you will see all HTTP requests send, if request to google is send when you click the button it mean that it work as expected, also you can remove the cookies from Application tab.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that everything is working as it should be :)